# DIV layout in two column format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html

I need to show list of categories in two column format with first column to show 1-7 & second column to show 7-15 categories

I am using ASP.Net repeater control to display my categories & comes like as show in [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/)

ASP.Net Code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategoryList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="footer-menu-item">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hylnkArticle" CssClass="footer-menu-links" ToolTip ='<%# getCategoryName(Eval("Name"))%>' NavigateUrl='<%#getCategoryURL(Eval("URL") %>' runat="server" BorderWidth="0">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Text='<%# getCategoryName(Eval("Name"))%>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<!-- Categories -->
```

My desired output should show up as

```
1      8
2      9
3      10
4      11
5      12
6      13
7      14
```

Is this format possible using CSS or one has to use jQuery, I dont want to do it in from code-behind using literal control & our design requirement might in near future. ISo i want to achieve this using CSS or jQuery.

I also tried different css properties which didn't work

HTML CODE sample

```
<div class="footer-content-column-one">
<!-- Categories -->  
    <div class="footer-mt">CATEGORIES</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">1</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">2</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">3</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">4</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">5</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">6</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">7</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">8</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">9</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">10</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">11</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">12</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">13</div>
    <div class="footer-menu-item">14</div>
<!-- Categories -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this fiddle suffices : http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/5/
Just used typical jQuery manipulation (and added border for visual hint):

```
var fi = $(".footer-menu-item");
fi.remove();   
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    fi.eq(i).css("clear","both").appendTo(".footer-content-column-one");
    fi.eq(i+7).appendTo(".footer-content-column-one");
}
```

Comment: Mr.Mshsayem good post. Thanks. Mr.Mshsayem and KnowledgeSeeker I did little bit changes in the fiddle posted by Mr.Mshsayem. Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/G7Uk2/6/ . This will handle both odd and event number of menu items and handle 'n' number of items (Up to my knowledge post by Mr.Mshsayem handle upto 14 menu items) I know the requirement of this question is only 14 menu items only. Just for more information I posted this fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok

```
<div style="clear:both;background-color:yellow;height:20em;width:40em">
    <div style="clear:both">
        <div style="float:left;width:20em;background-color:blue;">this is left</div>
        <div style="float:right;width:20em;background-color:red;">this is right</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
        <div style="float:left;width:20em;background-color:blue;">this is left</div>
        <div style="float:right;width:20em;background-color:red;">this is right</div>
    </div>  
            <div style="clear:both">
        <div style="float:left;width:20em;background-color:blue;">this is left</div>
        <div style="float:right;width:20em;background-color:red;">this is right</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
        <div style="float:left;width:20em;background-color:blue;">this is left</div>
        <div style="float:right;width:20em;background-color:red;">this is right</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: look at my update. as i had mentioned i am using asp.ner repeater control i cant us this. My list is generated from database.